# How to use ".contains" assertion to match one of the values

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, assertion, testcafe

As per my application, clicking on one of the links can open one of the URLs from two URLs.

Eg: Clicking on Link - X, it can open one of the below URLs :
http://example.com/value1 or http://example.com/value2

I have to write an **`.contains`** assertions for this which can look something like this:

```
expect(currentUrl).contains(value1 or value2)
```

As per the TestCafe documentation, contains does not have support for a regular expression and I do not want to use Match as I have to pass incomplete URL there.

Please let me know how this can be done.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using match assertion as below but still it would be good if this can be somehow done with contain assertion as well.

```
expect(currentUrl).match(/value1|value2$/)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following "current location" example test:

```
import { ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';

fixture `Fixture`
    .page `https://google.com`;

test('Check location', async t => {
    // Some actions and assertions...
    await t
        .navigateTo(/*...*/)
        .click(/*...*/);

    // Then check our location
    const getLocation = ClientFunction(() => document.location.href);
    const location    = await getLocation();

    await t
        .expect(location.includes('microsoft') || location.includes('google')).ok();
});
```